# Why does Django throw a 'does not exist' error when I try to add a field

Tags: python, django

Currently I'm using the default admin portal which is working fine.  Then inside models.py I try to add a field as follows:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # new field is 'info'
    info = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

MyModel has already been successfully defined and used in the above code I simply wish to add a single field. I rerun sync

```
python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

However then Django throws an error when I try to use the interface

```
column myproject_mymodel.info does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`manage.py syncdb` will only create tables that do not exist, it will not work for adding or removing columns, or for modifications to columns.

I suggest reading through the following chapter of the Django Book (which is free online):
[Chapter 10: Advanced Models](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10.html)

Here are the steps given in that chapter for adding fields:

> First, take these steps in the development environment (i.e., not on the production server):
>
> 1. Add the field to your model.
> 2. Run `manage.py sqlall [yourapp]` to see
>      the new `CREATE TABLE` statement for the model. Note the column
>      definition for the new field.
> 3. Start your database’s interactive
>      shell (e.g., `psql` or `mysql`, or you can use `manage.py dbshell`). Execute an `ALTER TABLE` statement that adds your new column.
> 4. Launch
>      the Python interactive shell with `manage.py shell` and verify that
>      the new field was added properly by importing the model and
>      selecting from the table (e.g., `MyModel.objects.all()[:5]`). If you
>      updated the database correctly, the statement should work without
>      errors.
>
> Then on the production server perform these steps:
>
> 1. Start your database’s interactive shell.
> 2. Execute the `ALTER TABLE` statement you used in step 3 of the development environment steps.
> 3. Add the field to your model. If you’re using source-code revision control and you checked in your change in development environment step 1, now is the time to update the code (e.g., `svn update`, with Subversion) on the production server.
> 4. Restart the Web server for the code changes to take effect.